# How to convert a list of text with dates and purchases into a table that shows purchases for every date with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to convert a list of text into a table that shows all the purchases for a particular date.

The data looks like this, and it is all in one column:

[image]

The data follows the format of:

1. Job Number
2. Price
3. Date
4. Email of customer
5. Product code

I am trying to convert the data into a table which will end up looking like this:

[image]

I would like to see all the purchases listed below the dates.

Is this possible with VBA in Excel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this question is too broad to be a good fit on this site - please see the [help/on-topic]; the answer to your question as stated, is "Yes". *How to get there* though, is a much broader question, wich many possible answers. Try to implement a solution yourself, and if/when you get stuck on a *specific programming issue*, you'll have a better-fitting question. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Mat'sMug, thanks for the explanation. I am new to VBA, so I had no idea where to start. I was hoping to find some sort of advice on what principles I should be looking at to solve the problem. I suppose I will just take it from the top :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an extremely inelegant solution to the problem, but without VBA.
Here is the original column of data:
[[orginal data]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMTjk.png)
In order to separate the dates into a separate column, I used this formula in column B:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),A2>40000),MONTH(A2)&"/"&DAY(A2)&"/"&YEAR(A2),"")
```

If you convert the date into a number, it will be greater than 40000, and since the purchases do not exceed 400000, we can see that all numbers greater than 40000 will be a date. Since the date includes the specific time of day, and we are only looking for the actual day, I used the MONTH, DAY, and YEAR questions to select only the date.

Next, I wanted to line up the purchases with the respective dates for the orders, so I used this formula to check to see if the value in column A is a number, and if it is, copy it over to column C.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1<40000),A1,"")
```

The formula was placed in C2 so that it lines up the purchases with the dates.
The spreadsheet now looks like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec8fA.png)

Next, you select columns B and C and create a pivot table- problem solved!